# Collapsible div in flex container opens the other divs as well

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a group of expandable divs inside a CSS flex container .

Codepen - https://codepen.io/vijayvmenon/pen/bGNRwvd

CSS:

```
.collapsible {
  background-color: #777;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.content {
  padding: 0 18px;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
```

When I click on any div, the other divs in the row also expand. How can I fix this by expanding only the div I clicked and not expanding the other divs in the row?

I am using the flex container because im building a responsive page and there are more components, which are not included here. Is it possible to do with a flex/grid container ? Please let me know. 
Any other solution by which I can wrap the divs and make it responsive should be fine.

I created a similar issue where I am using the polymer framework - [Collapsible div inside a CSS grid container expands full width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59462832/collapsible-div-inside-a-css-grid-container-expands-full-width)

Since I didn't get any help here, thought of creating one in Vanilla Javascript. Please help.

Note: I don't know the actual number of items beforehand and it is rendered using a "dom-repeat" in polymer library.So I can only have a container div enclosing the complete set of items. I can't have enclosing divs for each column of items (unless there is a way to do that)

Comment: The other divs aren't actually expanding because you can't see the hidden text.

Comment: It is something to do with the layout, right? You can inspect the elements and see that the max-height on the other divs with class "content" are still 0, when one div is expanded. Also, if you reduce the screen width and the divs are stacked vertically, the issue is not there. I feel its something to do with the flex container. But not sure how to fix it.

Comment: It is because when having a `flex-direction: row;` and `flex-wrap: wrap;` you'll create rows with items contained in each one of them. So the rows expand as the items inside if it force it to. You'll need a column structure in which items can move vertically. But that is more difficult to solve with only CSS.

Comment: Is the column amount always 3?

Comment: It is responsive. Column count depends on the number of items in the list. If the screen is big like for example in a Mac, it would display three columns because of the flex container and the availability of more space. In smaller screens it would display 2 columns and in mobile, it would stack vertically.

Comment: I think I can provide a good responsive answer. but there are several points: -1 this will not use a flexbox because I don't think this is possible with -2 I will need a little time to properly prepare my answer, will you have patience? -3 the last time I answered a Bounty, the PO to let time pass before I can validate my answer. I don't even know if he read it because it didn't give me any feedback! Will you look at my answer and consider validating it if it is appropriate? Please answer me!

Comment: Will sure do, Mister Jojo :-) . I have a possible solution by Richard below which I am checking as well.

Comment: Jojo, I was able to implement this using Richards solution below. Thanks!

Comment: I just post mine, have a look....

Comment: I asked you to have the patience to wait for my answer, and you answered me positively ... and I did not receive your messages because you never preceded them by my name with an at sign!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the code below (vanilla JS as I don't use polymer). It is responsive and will adjust the amount of column based on your `item` width (which I assume you will change using `media-query`). The idea is:

- Measure the `item` width you specified in CSS by creating a dummy item
- Adjust the number of columns needed based on measured `item` width. It is necessary to wrap the items in columns because it shouldn't be possible to do what you want by wrapping everything in one single flex container.
- Create the elements dynamically using vanilla JS (use polymer in your case)
- Add items to the columns one by one
- The logic for clicking is still the same as yours

Here is the full working example:

```js
let container = document.querySelector('.container')
let columnAmount = (() => {
  let containerWidth = parseInt(getComputedStyle(container).width)
  let dummyItem = document.createElement('div')
  let itemWidth

  dummyItem.classList.add('item') 
  container.appendChild(dummyItem)
  itemWidth = parseInt(getComputedStyle(dummyItem).width)
  dummyItem.remove()

  return Math.floor(containerWidth / itemWidth)
})()

let newColumns = []
for (let i = 0; i < columnAmount; i++) {
  newColumns.push(document.createElement('div'))
  newColumns[i].classList.add('item')
  container.appendChild(newColumns[i])
}


let childAmount = 11 // Change this to your needs
let newChild
let newCollapsibleButton
let newContent
let newContentParagraph
for (let i = 0; i < childAmount; i++) {
  newChild = document.createElement('div')
  newCollapsibleButton = document.createElement('button')
  newContent = document.createElement('div')
  newContentParagraph = document.createElement('p')

  newChild.classList.add('item--inner')
  newCollapsibleButton.classList.add('collapsible')
  newContent.classList.add('content')

  newCollapsibleButton.appendChild(document.createTextNode(`Open Section ${i + 1}`))
  newContentParagraph.appendChild(document.createTextNode(`Section ${i + 1} Details`))

  newContent.appendChild(newContentParagraph)
  newChild.appendChild(newCollapsibleButton)
  newChild.appendChild(newContent)

  newColumns[i % columnAmount].appendChild(newChild)
}

let collapsibleButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".collapsible");
for (let i = 0; i < collapsibleButtons.length; i++) {
  collapsibleButtons[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    let content = this.nextElementSibling;

    this.classList.toggle("active");
    content.style.maxHeight = content.style.maxHeight ? null : `${content.scrollHeight}px`
  });
}
```

```css
.container {
  display:flex;
  justify-content:space-between;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
}

.item {
  width: 30%;
}

.item--inner {
  width: 100%;
}

.collapsible {
  background-color: #777;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.content {
  padding: 0 18px;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
```

```html
<div class = "container">
</div>
```

Note that it doesn't handle page resizing, i.e. the items will be at that fixed state on page load (handle page resizing whenever necessary). <s>For convenience, adjust the screen size of this JSFiddle: [here](https://jsfiddle.net/rcmhzw4e/) and see how it reacts to different screen sizes. Running on the above snippet only allows one column of items as on load, the `container` size is pretty limited.</s> I have adjusted so that an `item` has `item--inner` and allows the `item` to always be 30% of the container size. If you don't want it to always be 30% of its container size, simply correct the CSS styling of `item`. For easier code adjustment, see JSFiddle here: [here](https://jsfiddle.net/rcmhzw4e/).

*Note: Change `item` width back to 400px if you want to see the two-columned version and the vertically stacked version. Make sure to adjust the screen size before the page has loaded.*

Comment: Thanks Richard. I will try this out tomorrow in Polymer and check if its a feasible solution. Will let you know.

Comment: Richard, Thanks a lot for this solution. I was able to implement this in polymer. Much appreciated!!

Comment: @VijayMenon Glad I could help.

Answer (score 2):

Well, this is my solution...

it create a new div on each column, and dispach all item inside. on window resize it create more or less columns, to respect responsive case

here is my code:

```js
(function () {
  const Container = document.querySelector('.container')
    ,   All_item  = [...document.querySelectorAll('.item')]
    ;
  if ( All_item.length===0 ) return 

  const items_W = All_item[0].offsetWidth        // get item width 
    ,   divGpr  = document.createElement('div')  // base col element
    ,   flexCol = []                             // array of ihm cols
    ;
  divGpr.style.width = items_W+'px';             // perfect size

  function SetNewCols()   //
    {
    let nbCol = Math.max(1, Math.floor( Container.offsetWidth / items_W ) )
      , len   = flexCol.length;
    if (nbCol===len) return     // col unchanged

    for(let k=0;k<nbCol;k++)    // create new Col
      { flexCol.push( Container.appendChild(divGpr.cloneNode(true))) }

    let k=0;
    for(item of All_item)
      {
      flexCol[len+k].appendChild(item)  // dispach item in new col
      k = ++k % nbCol                   // future col of
      }
    for(i=0;i<len;i++)
      { Container.removeChild( flexCol.shift() ) } // remove old empty cols
    if(k>0)
      { flexCol[( flexCol.length -1)].appendChild(item) }
    }

  SetNewCols();  // first Attempt

  window.addEventListener('resize', SetNewCols); 

  document.querySelectorAll(".container button").forEach(Koll=>
    {
    Koll.onclick=e=>
      {
      let content = Koll.nextElementSibling;
      content.style.maxHeight = Koll.classList.toggle("active")
                              ? content.scrollHeight + "px"
                              : 0;
      }
    })
})();
```

```css
.container {
  display:flex;
  justify-content:space-between;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
}
.container .item {
  width:400px;
}
.container .item > button {
  background-color: #777;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
}
.container .item .content {
  padding: 0 18px;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
```

```html
  <div class="container">
    <div class="item">
      <button>Open Section 1</button>
      <div class="content">
        <p>Section 1 details</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <button>Open Section 2</button>
      <div class="content">
        <p>Section 2 details</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <button>Open Section 3</button>
      <div class="content">
        <p>Section 3 details</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <button>Open Section 4</button>
      <div class="content">
        <p>Section 4 details</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <button>Open Section 5</button>
      <div class="content">
        <p>Section 5 details</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <button>Open Section 6</button>
      <div class="content">
        <p>Section 6 details</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: @VijayMenon I would like, on your part, to have at least a feedback....

Comment: Thanks a lot for your solution. Looks really elegant and handles resize as well. Appreciate your effort in this . I have upvoted your answer. I have already implemented Richards solution and its working fine. So that is still my accepted answer. Again, Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is to create a column-like structure, grouping all column elements into a div with class item:

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">
    <div class="item">
      <button class="collapsible">Open Section 1</button>
        <div class="content">
          <p>Section 1 details</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <button class="collapsible">Open Section 4</button>
      <div class="content">
        <p>Section 4 details</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  ...
</div>
```

I leave you the modified [CodePen](https://codepen.io/JosepRivaille/pen/RwNgzbG?editors=1100)! Hope this is what you wanted to do!

Comment: thanks for the response Josep. Let me try it out in my webpage and see if it works. I will update here.

Comment: I think I again simplified the question. I actually don't know the number of items inside and it is loaded using a dom-repeat in polymer library. Your approach requires  that I should know the number of elements beforehand. Apologize for not making it clear in the actual question. I have modified it now. is it possible to do it if the content is dynamic and loaded using a repeat function?

Answer (score 0):

In my approach, I'll use `$(document).on('click', '.collapsible', function () {});`

```
let $collBtn = '.item > .collapsible'; // all collapse
    $(document).on('click', '.collapsible', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $($collBtn).removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });
```

Once `.collabsible` has a class `active` it will expand the element like a togleClass(). Base on my experience when I have a multiple buttons and by using `$(document).on('click', '.item', function () {})` It's equivalent of finding a class && buttons in the same elements. Hopefully, this can help. :)

Comment: Felix, I did not understand your solution. It would be helpful if you can show using a codepen demo.

Answer (score 0):

@Vijay:- This is not an issue but a normal behaviour. When you click on any div, the other divs in the row are not expanding but the content is taking it's place and pushing other elements below that row to provide space for content to appear. You can only go with Position relative and absolute logic with the same HTML structure.

```
  *{
     box-sizing:border-box;
    }
    .item{
       position:relative;
    }
    .content {
      padding: 0 18px;
      max-height: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
      transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
      background-color: #f1f1f1;
      position:absolute;
      top:100%;
      left:0;
      right:0;

    }
```